# Why don't the panels backfeed the circuit in this 555 charge controller?

Tags: solar-charge-controller, voltage-source

[image: schematic]

<sub>Source: [Michael Davis Publishing (Mike's World) - A New & Improved Charge Controller Based on the 555 Chip](https://mdpub.com/555Controller/)</sub>

In this circuit, the positive of the batteries and solar cells are shorted together when the battery voltage is below 14.9V, but if the solar cells have a voltage of 20 is that not going to make it appear to the circuit that the battery has a much higher voltage hence switching it off? How do these two voltage sources appear to the circuit when they are in parallel?  Presumably something happens that causes the circuit not to get switched off but I don't understand why.

I had thought perhaps there was something super convenient that meant that the voltage from the two sources is just the battery voltage because it is sinking current from the solar panels - but I don't know how to check if that is the case.

Furthermore, if I put a voltage regulator between solar panels and the battery will it still read the battery voltage or the charging voltage?

I have looked at [the answer here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/431931/different-voltage-sources-in-parallel) and googling typical internal resistances of solar panels I got 0.5 ohms and for batteries at 4 ohms as answer, but putting them into the equation in the answer
20(4/4.5) + 12(0.5/4.5) it would appear that the panels are 8x more important in the output voltage

I am not good at circuit analysis and am not sure what I've missed. If someone could point it out to me that would be fantastic.

Comment: A solar panel isn't a voltage source, it is (roughly) a current source over most of its I-V characteristic.

Comment: @ocrdu aha thanks! I had not realised that, I had falsely assumed it was a voltage source.

Comment: So if I connected this circuit to my solar panels it would charge the lead acid battery in constant current mode and then disconnect when that causes the voltage to increase? If a current source is in parallel with a voltage source how do you apply KVL?

Comment: Which size of battery / solar cell are we talking about here? Why the hell do people insist on using the 555 for such things? I swear, sometimes looking at how hobbyist electronics are designed is equivalent to someone trying to figure out how to bake a quake, bread, or croissants, but for some unclear reason they decide that every recipe needs to contain at least one muddy pinecone. The muddy pinecone is the 555 here. You don't *need* a 555 to build a charge controller. In fact, it's pretty much the worst choice of a component you could find for that application.

Comment: to make matters worse, this schematic is intentionally operating the NE555 at 5V – which *really* is marginally close to the minimum voltage that would still work here. This whole circuit is an excellent method to drain the battery you're supposed to be charging when there's no sun. I mean, who comes up with this nonsense? And how is the NE555 usage contests (cake with muddy pinecones contest?!) and this wins? uuugh! (bit disappointed by one of the hosts of that contest; I know they know better.)

Comment: @Bren to answer the question of what happens when you connect your solar cells to your battery with this circuit is that you run a) get a very inefficient charger, because this has *no* operation point control for the solar cell, at all. It's not a charge controller, even if they call it that. And b) you run a fair chance of damaging your solar cells, because there's no backflow protection, and just a slow, temperature-dependent comparator switching the solar cell off.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: There's nothing wrong with using the 555 here -- after all, it's basically two comparators and a flip-flop, which is exactly the functionality that's required! But I agree, there's no need for a power-wasting regulator; just run the whole thing at 12 V.